# PCI Compliance: Insecure configuration of Cookie attributes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

The PCI compliance checking found this issue on our site: "Insecure configuration of Cookie
attributes". Magento Version: 2.3.5-p1

Here are the Default Cookie Settings:

[image]

The Base URL and Secure Base URL are already using https.

How will we be able to set the secure flag on all cookies to true?

Answer (score 1):

Hi please follow this official fix as this has also been raised on git

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2d1f8ca5d13c626000b34002704de9e0a99d3d99

Comment: hi, i checked each file in the commit and seems it is already included in the version we are already using which is  2.3.5-p1. i wonder why it still does not work?

Comment: then i would suggest you to raise it again if you are already done with the your debugging stuff